# How to convert arbitrary large integer from arbitrary base to a different base?

Tags: c++, windows, numbers, gmp

I have a base-n (unsigned) integer that is hundreds of thousands characters long.

How can I convert this number (which is a string read from a file) to any base between 2-256? In reasonable time of course.

GMP library supports only bases 2-62.

Answer (score 5):

GMP uses [a clever divide-and-conquer radix change algorithm](http://gmplib.org/manual/Binary-to-Radix.html) for really big integers.

It's not hard to do something that uses the same basic idea.  Call your radix `r` and the input number `x`.

Let `rp[i] = r^(2^i)` for each `i` up until `rp[i]` has about half the number of bits of your original number; call the last one `rp[n-1]`.  Reduce your number modulo `rp[n-1]`.  Then the high `2^(n-1)` radix-`r` digits are those of `x / rp[n-1]` converted to base-`r`, and the low radix-`r` digits are those of `x % rp[n-1]` converted to base-`r`.  Notice that you only have to compute `rp` once.

This is rather more efficient than extracting a single digit at a time since we reduce a `k`-bit number to two roughly `k/2`-bit numbers, instead of a `log(r)`-bit number and a `k-log(r)`-bit number.